# System.Security.SecurityException with GoDaddy Hosting

Tags: asp.net

net.my application is working fine on localhost.Till yesterday my application working fine on godaddy.But i do some changes in coding(there i used Viewstate) and then upload it to the godaddy.But now if i logged in to the index page,every thing is working as earlier.But if i click radio button(for which i have changed coding),it will give the  System.Security.SecurityException error.The Error is as follows.i have doubt that whether using viewstate property caused this error..?.

```
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Assembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +150
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +100
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +284
   System.Security.PermissionSetTriple.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet demandSet, PermissionSet& alteredDemandset, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh) +69
   System.Security.PermissionListSet.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet pset, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh) +150
   System.Security.PermissionListSet.DemandFlagsOrGrantSet(Int32 flags, PermissionSet grantSet) +30
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.DemandFlagsOrGrantSet(Int32 flags, PermissionSet grantSet) +40
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32 permission, PermissionSet targetGrant, CompressedStack securityContext) +123
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32 permission, PermissionSet targetGrant, Resolver accessContext) +41
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this the error that happens when one machine in a web farm renders a page, then it gets posted back to a different machine in the web farm? If so, you need to have a common machine key in a config file on each server in the farm (typically in the `machine.config`).

Comment: i didnot understand your point.But i did not use any machine.config file.

Comment: @Mallikarjuna, I may be completely wrong, it was just a guess. But ASP.Net performs some kind of security check on postback data to ensure it originated from the same server. Obviously in a web farm (lots of servers running the same code) sometimes server A will send out a page, and it will be posted back to server B. To tell ASP.Net this is ok, all the servers need to have a common machine key in configuration. This will be an issue for GoDaddy I believe. Maybe raise a support ticket or something?